# Programmatically retrieve SAP BPC Dynamic Script source code

Tags: abap, sap-bw, badi

I would like to know how to retrieve the source code of a SAP BPC package Dynamic Script.

I'll try to explain: in SAP BPC I can write a component called Dynamic Script, I can save the source using the Excel Addin.

The Dynamic Script is associated to a SAP BPC "Package", and is a piece of code that can call an ABAP BAdI.

What I would like to know is how this piece of code is stored in BW, how it is linked to the relative package, and how to programmatically retrieve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the Microsoft version, there's a DTSX file associated with packages not sure for NW though